# how to pass input value using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have more than 5 card types and each card as different validation, when user change the card type, the `reqpattern` will change and i need to pass changed `reqpattern` in `callonkeyup` function.
Please tell me how to pass changed `reqpattern` in `callonkeyup` function.

```
callonkeyup(this,'AccountNumber',this.getAttribute('reqpattern'))

<input type="tel" reqpattern="^[0-9]+\$" 
  onblur="callonkeyup(this,'AccountNumber',this.getAttribute('reqpattern'));" 
  value="" id="AccountNumber"/>
```

Comment: why don't you paste the work you've done so far so we can better help you...  EDIT: thanks for edit @Jayesh

Comment: how user change the card type??? clicking some element or using dropdown etc...

Answer (score 1):

Why not just pass the req pattern within the function call:

```
 <input type="tel" onblur="callonkeyup(this,'AccountNumber', '^[0-9]+\$');" value="" id="AccountNumber"/>
```

Comment: Hi Reinder Wit, reqpattern is dynamic, it will be updating when user change the card types

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to reproduce your issue with your code.
I have tried with the below code snippet, Can you please check it at your hand?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<title>Test</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="tel" reqpattern="^[0-9]+\$" 
  onblur="callonkeyup(this,'AccountNumber',this.getAttribute('reqpattern'));" 
  value="" id="AccountNumber"/>
<input type="tel" reqpattern="^[a-z]+\$" 
  onblur="callonkeyup(this,'AccountName',this.getAttribute('reqpattern'));" 
  value="" id="AccountName"/>

<script>
function callonkeyup(obj,txtType,rpattern)
{
    alert(obj);
    alert(txtType);
    alert(rpattern);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Let me know if any concern.